# Get remote openssl software version without logging in

Tags: bash, shell, automation, openssl

I would like to check the version of openssl without having to log in to each server and typing

```
openssl version
```

There's about 100 IP addresses I have. Can I get some direction on how this could be done with a bash script passing in a word-list with all IP addresses ?

I'm aware of configuration management tools ( Saltstack, Chef, etc.. ) but that brings me back to logging in and installing agents on each server. I rather not do at this time.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit:** I didn't notice you were asking for openssl, not openssh.

If you put the remote host data in a file *hosts* like

```
user1@host1
user2@host2
```

you can use

```
cat hosts | xargs -I % sh -c 'printf "%: " ; ssh % openssl version'
```

And, as @jww commented, this would be rather a question for [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/)

Comment: openssh != openssl

Comment: @Cyrus: thx for the hint; I changed my answer accordingly

Comment: That's a [useless use of `cat`](http://www.iki.fi/era/unix/award.html).  `xargs` has an `-a` option you can use to pass in a file without redirecting it explicitly, or you can use `xargs <hosts`